# How to get rid of cooking smell in small apartment?

Tags: smell

I live in a small studio apartment. It doesn't have Air conditioner, and apartment window have really small opening. I keep that open always. Recently I have starting cooking at home ( its been 2months ).  I must say every time I come home after work I can smell that.

How can I totally get rid of cooking smell?  I heard about diffuser and soy candles.  Does that work for you?  Some says diffuser is not good for health.

What do you use to keep your apartment smell good?

Comment: Can you selectively eject the cooking vapors (e.g. an over-the-stove vent system)? I think that would be the most effective technique by far.

Comment: Yes I do that. But still my apartment gets cooking smell.

Comment: If you have a vent over the stove, make sure it's the story that actually extracts the air. The recirculating sort do work but only if you change the filters frequently. With an extracting cooker hood you need to get the airflow right: either shut the kitchen door and open the window, or open only the window in the room you're most worried about keeping the smell from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ventilation, ventilation, ventilation is the only safe way to keep any building smelling good plus dehumidification. You must be sure your range hood is not the recirculating type. ie; If it blows the air back into the space it does not vent outdoors. If it does vent outdoors and does not suck the cooking vapors to the level desired you may need to equalize the pressure by opening a window in another portion of the space to make up the lost air from the ventilation fan. When showering always use the bathroom fan and/or open a window. Fans on timers are always best. Set to 60 minutes after leaving a shower to dry the room out. Dehumidification may be a requirement if fans do not help. This will help maintain low odor thresholds in any home. High humidity above 50% rh (relative humidity) will increase indoor odors and mold growth. To dehumidify you can use window fans and in some cases mechanical dehumidification may be required. (Dehumifier) 
You can review the ASHRAE 62.2 or 62.1 standards for the heating and ventilation industry. Never resort to scented candles or air fresheners as they may release toxins into your living space eventually making you ill.

https://www.ashrae.org/resources--publications/bookstore/standards-62-1--62-2

Answer (score 0):

Given that you live in a studio apartment with very limited ventilation space, it is important to have a good exhaust fan/ air purifier and a dehumidifier to get rid of the pesky smell and damp air. You can also counteract the food smell by placing bowls of vinegar all over your apartment or simmer baking soda on a pan to get rid of odors. You can also boil citrusy fruits such as lemon and oranges, or herbs such as mint, sage, and lavander to naturally diffuse aroma in your space.